# Sending one signal push notifications in one by one

Tags: node.js, push-notification, ionic2, onesignal

I have array of object which include playerid and userinfo to send. Is it possible to send as push notification as one by one with rest api call. Is it possible to loop all device ids to complete.
How can i achieve this with REST api call. Thanks in advance.

I have information something like this

```
[
  {
    "deviceid": 12345678534549,
    "userinfo": "Hello venkatesh"
  },
  {
    "deviceid": 123456435910010,
    "userinfo": "Hello Pradeep"
  },
  {
    "deviceid": 123445535356789,
    "userinfo": "Hello Chaitanya"
  }
]

for(var i =0; i< pushinfo.length; i++){
                    var message = {
                        app_id: "myappid",
                        contents: { "en": pushinfo[i].userinfo },
                        include_player_ids: [pushinfo[i].deviceid],
                        data: { "notification": 'rpi_alarm' }
                    };
                    sendNotification(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use for native, you can use asynchronous eachSeries when you push notification.

var async = require('async')

```
var data =
 [
  {
    "deviceid": 12345678534549,
    "userinfo": "Hello venkatesh"
  },
  {
    "deviceid": 123456435910010,
    "userinfo": "Hello Pradeep"
  },
  {
    "deviceid": 123445535356789,
    "userinfo": "Hello Chaitanya"
  }
]

async.eachSeries(data,function(item,cb){
    playerIds.push(item.deviceid)
    var message = {
        app_id: "myappid",
        contents: { "en": item.userinfo },
        include_player_ids: item.deviceid,
        data: { "notification": 'rpi_alarm' }
    };
    cb()
})
```